# android asynTask to activity problem ?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I develop an GPS app. my app have a service that responsible to send GPS to server through server....

```
Service -----> AysncTask(sendServer)
// then in service i broadcast some variable

myFilteredResponse = new Intent(GPS_FILTER);
        myFilteredResponse.putExtra("latitude",      Double.valueOf(twoFormat.format(location.getLatitude())));
        myFilteredResponse.putExtra("longitude", Double.valueOf(twoFormat.format(location.getLongitude())));
        myFilteredResponse.putExtra("network", MyGPS.cur_network_status);
```

then in my Activity I create a broadcast receiver to receive all these variable n it works fine, my UI then will change when we have new lat n lon

in my AysncTask when send to server i will get the location identify by server so i want to update my UI interface so i 1 2 use broadcast as well but it's not work !

structure

```
                                  broadcast
service ( on location changed ) ------------->   UI interface

            broadcast??
AsyncTask ------------->   UI interface
```

i can't use sendBroadcast in my AsyncTask since my AsyncTask is not activity any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you problem is to get the data from the service.

you can bind the service to the UI and call the service from within the activity.

here is an opensource project. [Link](http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/browse/trunk/OpenGPSTracker/trunk/application/).

this is the service code. [Link](http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/browse/trunk/OpenGPSTracker/trunk/application/src/nl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/logger/).

this is the UI. [Link](http://code.google.com/p/open-gpstracker/source/browse/trunk/OpenGPSTracker/trunk/application/src/nl/sogeti/android/gpstracker/viewer/LoggerMap.java)

**EDIT:**
if you want to do UI updates using AsyncTask then you can use **onPostExecute** which runs in UI thread.

**EDIT:**
Here you go. AsyncTask Example. [Link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: Thx , but i use broadcast so that my UI's static member can't catch the info broadcast from the service ( it's fine ) the problem is in the asyncTask class that after i got response from server i want to update my UI,

Comment: are you updating the ui from OnPostExecute in the asyncTask

Comment: in my AsyncTask 
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  Log.d(tag, "post executed "+result);
  // do sth here
  //MyGPS.location_info = "UnKnown";
  //
               //   want to broadcast the response to UI can i??
 }

what i do is just make member of the UI equal to response so i think if i can broadcast that out i can update my UI

Comment: in post exectue i can change the value of the location that get from server but the problem i have to restart the activity if not it will not change

Comment: onPostExecute runs ON ui thread, so the ui can be updated directly. no need to broadcast.

Comment: can u give me some example cuz i'm just start learn android :)